# CSS Sticky Footer - Never works right for me

Tags: css, sticky-footer

I've been trying to make this work for a while and it never seems to work out.  I think its because my HTML structure is slightly different than the ones in the example.  My problem is, on pages that are smaller than the viewport, the footer is not automatically pushed to the bottom, and the #main div is not extended to the footer.

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id='container'>
            <div id='main'>
                <div id='content'> </div>
            </div>
            <div id='footer'> </div>
        </div>
     </body>
</html>
```

And here would be my basic CSS, without implementation of CSS Sticky Footer:

```
div#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
div#main {
    background-color:black
    padding-bottom:30px;
}

div#content {
    width:425px;
}

div#footer {
    position:relative;
    bottom:0;
    width:inherit;
    height:90px;
}
```

To clarify:  Lets say the background of div#main is black.  Now lets say, on a page, there's only 1 line of text in div#main.  So I want to make the #main area extend all the way down to the footer (which is at the bottom of the page) even when there isn't enough content to force that to happen.  make sense?

And One more thing.  The #main area has a different background color than the body.  So the #main background has to extend all the way down to the footer, cause if there's a gap, the body color peaks through instead

Comment: Are you trying to have the footer remain on the bottom of the viewport at all times?

Comment: yes.  but in adittion to that, my #main div, I want to extend down to the footer at all times.  So lets say there's only 1 line of text in div#main, but the background of #main is black, I want the black aera to extend all the way down to the footer, even if theres not enough content in #main to force it to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/keeping-footers-at-the-bottom-of-the-page

**EDIT**

Using the technique in the article above (tested - *and* works in fiddle):

*HTML*

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id='container'>
        <div id='main'>
            <div id='content'>Hello</div>
        </div>
        <div id='footer'> </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

*CSS*

```
html, body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;
}
div#container,div#main {
    background-color: #333;
}
div#container {
    min-height:100%; width:960px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;
}
div#main {
    padding-bottom:90px; margin:0; padding:10px;
        }
div#content {
    width:425px;
}
div#footer {
    position:absolute; bottom:0; width: 100%; height:90px; background-color: #ADF;
}
```

Comment: hm, i guess what different about that is his container is white background, as is his body background.  With me, my body background is one color, and the container is another.  So the footer can sit at the bottom, but you see the container color end halfway through the page...

Comment: i was about to say this doesn't work because your #container and #main are the same color.  So in actually, the #main is not extending all the way down to the Footer...just the container is.  BUT, if I put the footer inside the #container, i realized I can make the #container the same color, in which case it does work! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try making the footer `position:fixed`.

http://jsfiddle.net/QwJyp/

**Update**

I'm a little bit closer: http://jsfiddle.net/QwJyp/1/. Perhaps somebody can build off it. If you remove the line with `!important` defined, it allows the main with `height:100%` to show up.  But there's still a lot of extra padding at the bottom of the div which I can't figure out.  I'll continue later when I have more time.  Good luck!  Hopefully this helps with some direction.

Comment: I'm not sure what that means, exactly.  Trying to get the green section to fill all the way to the footer?

Comment: yes, The question indicates that he'd like the content the extend to the footer - I'm not sure exactly which div needs to extend.

Comment: clarified my question.  Its the #main div that I want to extend down to the footer at all times

Comment: "the content" can be extended by adding more characters...perhaps some [link](http://www.lipsum.com/)?  So, then, are we talking about "the content panel"?  Do you see what I mean?  And why it's important to be explicit?

Comment: no, i don't wan to ad some link.  The StickyFooter seems to work for some people, just doesn't seem to be working in my particular scenario.  So I'd like to see if thats possible

Comment: The "link" is a Lipsum text generator. Your comment here wasn't visible on my screen at the time of my comment.  Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

idea is to have #main with padding-bottom x, container min-height: 100%, footer after container and with margin-top -x

Answer (score 0):

Try using with absolute position for the footer div

```
<div id='container'>
            <div id='main'>
                <div id='content'> </div>
            </div>
            <div id='footer'> </div>
        </div>
```

Make sure that body height is 100%

```
html,body
{   height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
div#container {
    width:960px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
}
div#main {
    background-color:black;
    padding-bottom:90px;
}

div#content {
    width:425px;
}

div#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:inherit;
    height:90px;
    width:960px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the html is structured differently than what you're working with, but perhaps you can alter your core structure to mimic this (because it works): [CSS Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/using-sticky-footer-code.html)

It looks like this group has done a lot of research on the topic and have found this it be the best (maybe the only?) way...through many different versions.